# Streaming mic audio from Linux PC client to Pi host and sending result back to PC

Tags: networking, audio

I have a task that I'm trying to achieve that seems incredibly over complicated to do. So I have a raspberry pi at a remote location I cannot access. Then I have access to an Ubuntu laptop. What I would like to do is send audio from my laptops microphone to my Pi so it can be used in a node js script, then play a file that is on my Pi out of the speakers of my laptop. 
Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: This is too broad for this site.  You need a whole hardware-software system designed.  If you try and have specific problems with some approach, you might be able to get help with those if you provide details.

Comment: Record the audio on your laptop, upload it to a file hosting service, download it from the RPi using wget; simple.